# Copy Text From Texit_Input

Tags: python, copy, kivy, clipboard, bubble-popup

I need to copy the text to later use
At pressing (ctrl + c), There will be error
So I used bubble, but the same error appears

*****Python********

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.lang import Builder

class Progress(Popup):
    pass
class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):
    pass

class Func(Screen):
    pass

presentation = Builder.load_file("try_.kv")

class MainApp(App):
    Progress = Progress()
    def build(self):
        return presentation
if __name__ == "__main__":
    MainApp().run()
```

*****KV File*******

```
#:import Factory kivy.factory.Factory
# #:import Clipboard kivy.core.clipboard.Clipboard
<Progress>:
    text: ""
    separator_color: 0, 0, 0, 0

    BoxLayout:
        TextInput:
            id: textinput
            text: "Your Key is samphone"
            copydata: 'text'
            readonly: True
            use_bubble: True
            allow_copy: True

        Button:
            text: "Click"
            on_release:
                root.dismiss()

ScreenManagement:
    Func:

<Func>:
    BoxLayout:
        Button:
            text: "Click"
            on_release:
                Factory.Progress().open()
```

****Error*****

> File
>   "C:\Users\Sherif\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\textinput.py",
>   line 378, in do
>        textinput.copy()    File "C:\Users\Sherif\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\textinput.py",
>   line 1712, in copy
>        return Clipboard.copy(self.selection_text)    File "C:\Users\Sherif\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\clipboard__init__.py",
>   line 73, in copy
>        self._copy(data)    File "C:\Users\Sherif\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\clipboard__init__.py",
>   line 87, in _copy
>        self.put(data, self._clip_mime_type)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\Sherif\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\clipboard\clipboard_winctypes.py",
>   line 55, in put
>        msvcrt.wcscpy_s(c_wchar_p(hCd), len(text), c_wchar_p(text))
>
> ValueError: embedded null character

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the following example for details:

## Example

### main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen


class Progress(Popup):
    pass


class Func(Screen):
    pass


class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):
    pass


class MainApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return ScreenManagement()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MainApp().run()
```

### main.kv

```
#:import Factory kivy.factory.Factory

<Progress>:
    text: ""
    separator_color: 0, 0, 0, 0

    BoxLayout:
        TextInput:
            id: textinput
            text: "Your Key is samphone"
            readonly: True
            allow_copy: True
            copydata: self.text

        Button:
            text: "Click"
            on_release:
                root.dismiss()

<Func>:
    BoxLayout:
        Button:
            text: "Click"
            on_release:
                Factory.Progress().open()

<ScreenManagement>:
    Func:
```

### Output - Paste Later

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the whole `ValueError` here is "only" about quite a recent(`3.5.4`+ and `3.6.3`+) change in the CPython internals in [this pull request](https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/2462) which basically for our ctypes clipboard meant calling a changed API `_PyUnicode_AsUnicode` instead of the original `PyUnicode_AsUnicode` and as [described in the commit message](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/0834905d9b61291b1fc5e05a1ffbc69de9c9379f):

> _PyUnicode_AsUnicode() which is similar to
>   PyUnicode_AsUnicode(), but checks for null characters..

it raised an error. It took a while to figure this one out because I didn't find it in the release notes, however it's fixed in [kivy#5579](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/pull/5579) and will be soon in master branch.